# Interpretaion : referred to as

Tags: objects, interpretation

In [the science article](http://www.nature.com/nchem/journal/v8/n9/full/nchem.2603.html), I found this sentence.

> In order to perform these distinct functions, proteins rely on the
>   precise 3D arrangement of functional groups — referred to as the
>   protein fold.

I think something should be after 'to' as an object.
But why it is like that? and what does it mean?

Comment: It has the same meaning as "Which is referred to as the protein fold" where "refer to" is a phrasal verb, and "as" is a preposition.

Comment: @Cardinal Then does the clause almost means like "which is reffered to something like the protein fold"?

Comment: I'm not sure about your meaning, but it means something like: "which is called 'the protein fold'  " IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a passive construction.

You can *refer to*  'the precise 3D arrangement of functional groups' as 'the protein fold' —which is using an active construction for *refer to*

or

You can say that 'the precise 3D arrangement of functional groups' (are) *referred to* as 'the protein fold'.

In the article, the linking verb *to be* is replaced by the hyphen (—)

Comment: ah now I understand what grammar is in, I always get confused when prasal verbs get into passive form.